# The implicit function theorem is not applicable to the system of equations $3x^3+2y^5-5t^7=0$, $2x^3-y^5-t^7=0$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem

I am given a system of equations:

$F_1(t,x,y)=3x^3+2y^5-5t^7$

$F_2(t,x,y)=2x^3-y^5-t^7$

The task is to show that the system is locally uniquely resolvable in the point $(t,x,y)=(0,0,0)$ in respect to the variables $x,y$.

So obviously the implicit function theorem cannot be used (since the matrix $D_2$ isn't invertible at the given point). But if I substitute $a=x^3,b=y^5$ the matrix $D_2$ becomes:

\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 2 \\
2 & -1 
\end{pmatrix}

and is invertible as such so now I can apply the implicit function theorem. Since $x^3,y^5$ are injective and continuous functions the system is locally uniquely resolvable in $x$ and $y$, because it is resolvable in $a,b$, which follows from the theorem.

Is this a correct way to solve this and if not where would this fail?

Comment: You will get unique solutions for $x$, $y$ real. But they might not be differentiable. A simpler example is solving for $x$ in $x^3 - t=0$.  The solution is $x = \sqrt[3]{t}$, continuous but not differentiable at $t=0$.  So, at  $(x,t) = (0,0)$, the implicit function theorem does not work, so you have this ad-hoc approach.

Comment: You have $(x^3,y^5,t^7)  = (w,w,w)  = w(1,1,1)  $   for real $w.$  We may introduce real $q$     with $w = q^{105},$  so that $(x^3,y^5,t^7)  =(q^{105},q^{105},q^{105})$ and $(x,y,t)  = (q^{35},q^{21},q^{15})$